# Joining dataframe by index. but no data on output, however the column names are joined

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

I am trying to join 2 dataframes by same index as the first column in both dataframes using python. The code is below:

```
combined_data = pd.merge(df1, df2, right_index=True, left_index=True)
```

df1 has columns:

```
colA, colB
```

And  df2 has:

```
colA, colC, colD, colE
```

**the output is:**

```
colA, colB, colC, colD, colE
```

with no data below it. It just gives the joined columns

**NOTE: The df has about 4800 rows and df2 has 4600 rows**
Could large data be a problem. Or there is something else wrong?

Comment: "Could large data be a problem?" Try it on a small data set. If that fails in the same way you can rule out that it is the size of the data set. It sounds like you are looking for `combined_data = pd.merge(left, right, on='colA')` but just a guess, an example of your input and desired output would help

Comment: Can you append the output of df1.head(5) and df2.head(5)?

Comment: @Mokshyam  well the code works on the dummy smaller data. My dataframe carries data from a table residing in the sqlite database, and may be are not in list form(just a guess, im new to df). could that be a reason or just that they carry large data??

Comment: Pandas can easily process 4800x2 and 4600x4 dataframes. You must give us some data to work with.

Comment: @Mokshyam  len(df1) = 4805 & len(df2) = 4805 but len(combined_data) = 0

Comment: Of course len gives the row number, but use shape. I reiterate, provide the head of the two dataframes.

Comment: @Mokshyam df1[:5] & df2[:5] produces fine result

Comment: Do they have indexes in common?`merge` use `inner` as default since you didn't explicit set `how`.And  `inner: use intersection of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL inner join; preserve the order of the left keys`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to a different data type for the same common column in two dataframes.
this can be resolved by:
df1['colA'] = df1['colA'].astype(int)
df2['colA'] = df2['colA'].astype(int)#to ensure both are int type.
after this the code works like charm!.